# How to load and navigate a website within a Cordova webview

Tags: android, cordova, android-webview, phonegap-plugins, cordovawebview

Hello I have built my website, was looking forward to have an app for my responsive website... I went with android webviews but it posed problems with opening filechooser... So I went with Cordova after doing a lot of research. I succeeded in creating a Cordova application an imported it to Android studio. My problem is, when my landing page opens clicking any other link opens the default browser... I don't want this behavior I want all links to open within the app(Using Cordova's webviews)...thanks in advance.

NOTE:Am using Cardova to open a completely remote website no local stuff.

My MainActivity.java look like this

```
package com.noel.myapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        loadUrl("http://www.mywebsite.com");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The inAppBrowser adds an additional address bar at the top. Instead if you just want in app navigation you can use this solution (*borrowed from comment section of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42946505/open-external-url-in-cordova-webview-not-inappbrowser))*

Add this line in your config.xml file

```
<allow-navigation href="*://*.example.com/*" />
```

and inside your index.js add something like this

```
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    // other code
    window.location = "https://www.example.com
}
```

*(Although this being an old thread sharing anyways if someone else comes across this)*

Answer (score 3):

use `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` for that

cordova docs for inappbrowser is [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/).

after device is ready (deviceready event)

use

`var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');`

after adding the plugin.

basic example is [here](http://javacourseblog.blogspot.in/2014/02/show-loading-screen-in-phonegap-app.html)